# How to use didReceiveMemoryWarning in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, didreceivememorywarning

My app has several UIViewControllers in a stack (under a UINavigationController). In certain cases I get memory warnings when I'm in the inner UIViewControllers (mostly happens if the device is overloaded with other applications running in the background). When these memory warnings occur the application keeps on running (most of the times) and then when it gets back to the `rootViewController` it reloads it but doesn't fill in the view objects (mostly UIButton images).

I wish to implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning`, but I'm not clear regarding to how to do that.

The end result I'm looking for is that when the application does this "reload" after memory warning it will "reload" `rootViewController` in the same status it was before the user started "diving" into the inner UIViewControllers.

- How should I do the implementation?
- Should I implement the default `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in each UIViewController?
- Since the memory warning always occur in the inner UIViewControllers, how should I let the `rootViewController` know that it should run `didReceiveMemoryWarning`?
- How do I tell the `rootViewController` which settings it should do? In other words - can I keep the settings someplace where `didReceiveMemoryWarning` doesn't delete them and upon activating `didReceiveMemoryWarning` "recall" them so the user will see the same screen they started the "levels navigation" from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non-visible view controller on the UINavigationController stack will dump its view.  It will also send you the warning. If you have large data structures being held by the view controllers you should dump those if possible.

The root (an other) controllers should appropriately handle `viewDidUnload` and be able to cycle through another `loadView`/`viewDidLoad` phase.

If you want the state to be the same, you need to be persisting all that information.  NSUserDefaults is a standard location to do that.

Comment: 1. So what you are saying regarding the UINavigationController stack is that while I'm in the 3rd view in the stack the system dumps the 2nd view?

Comment: 2. How should I do the implementation in the root view? What is my starting point for the didReceiveMemoryWarning? should I call loadView from within didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. definitely don't call `loadView` from `didReceive…`, you should never call `loadView`, only implement it.  The root view controller is just another view controller on the stack

Comment: OK, got it. One more thing, If I want to save some data before the didReceiveMemoryWarning takes effect (i.e. before it calls the viewDidLoad) so the application will reload the root view with the data it held before the memory warning had occured. any idea how to do that?

Comment: generally use `NSUserDefaults` to store stuff like where the table view is scrolled to and/or it's selection, when you receive a `viewDidLoad` you can reset that state